# Predicate not consistent

Tags: modeling, alloy

I have to realize an application which permits to reserve a seat in a store. There are no sintax error, but I don't understand why terminal  reply me "predicate not consistent". Can u help me?
This is my code:

```
open util/integer

sig Email{}
sig CF{}
sig Time{
    hour: one Int,
    minute:one Int,
    second: one Int
}

abstract sig RegisteredUser{

    email: one Email

}


sig User extends RegisteredUser{

    cf:  one CF

}

sig SM extends RegisteredUser{

    cf:  one CF,
    store: one Store

}

sig Location{}

sig Date{}

abstract sig Status {}
```

//only one of this can be true

```
one sig Waiting extends Status {}
one sig Expired extends Status{}
one sig Pending extends Status{}

sig Ticket{
    
    owner:one User,
    date: one Date,
    time: one Time,
    status : one Status,
        
}

sig Visit{

    owner:one User,
    date: one Date,
    time: one Time,
    duration:one Time,
    status : one Status,
    products: some Product,
    category: some Category,

}
```

//tickets are assumed with a  default duration time of 15 min and entrance one for time, so  4*8=32 visit per day

```
sig TicketQueue {
       
    max_visit:one Int,
    ticket: some Ticket,
    manager: one SM

}

sig VisitQueue{
       category: some Category,
    visit: some Visit,
    manager: one SM
} 

sig Store{
       max_simultaneous: one Int,
    location: one Location,
    visitqueue: one VisitQueue,
    ticketqueue: one TicketQueue,
    product_category: some Category

}

sig Category{
simultaneous_seats: one Int,
}

sig Product{

    category: one Category

}
```

// Constraints

// Registration data for the system are unique(Unique username and Fiscal Code)

```
fact registrationDataUniqueness { 
    
    no disjoint u1, u2: RegisteredUser | u1.email = u2.email
    no disjoint u1,u2: User | u1.cf = u2.cf
    no disjoint s1,s2: SM | s1.cf = s2.cf
    no disjoint s:SM, u:User | s.cf=u.cf

}
```

//Ticket and Visit can have only one of   status' values defined before

```
fact requestConsistency {

        all s: Status | (s = Waiting && s != Expired && s !=Pending ) || (s != Waiting && s = Expired && s != Pending) || (s !=Waiting && s != Expired && s = Pending)

}
```

//SM can manage only one Store

```
fact StoreUniqueness{

    no disjoint s1,s2: SM |s1.store=s2.store
}
```

// the same ticket or visit cannot be of two or more different user

```
 fact UserUniqueness{

    no disjoint t1,t2: Ticket | t1.owner=t2.owner
    no disjoint v1,v2: Visit | v1.owner=v2.owner

}
```

//different products can not be of the same category

```
fact CategoryUniqueness{

    no disjoint p1,p2: Product | p1.category=p2.category
}
```

//different stores can't have the same ticket or visit queue

```
fact QueueUniqueness{

    no disjoint s1,s2: Store | s1.ticketqueue=s2.ticketqueue
    no disjoint s1,s2: Store | s1.visitqueue=s2.visitqueue

}
```

//different tickets cannot have the same time

```
fact TimeUniqueness{

    no disjoint t1,t2: Ticket | t1.time = t2.time
}
```

//for semplicity,in the visit/ticket queue, we consider "active" only visit/ticket with Waiting status

```
fact StatusQueue{

    all tq:TicketQueue | tq.ticket.status=Waiting
    all vq:VisitQueue | vq.visit.status=Waiting

}
```

//one ticket/visit can not belong to two or more different queue

```
fact ReservationUniqueness{

    no disjoint tq1,tq2:TicketQueue | tq1.ticket=tq2.ticket
    no disjoint vq1,vq2:VisitQueue | vq1.visit=vq2.visit

}
```

//SM is unique for a specific store, and its related ticket/visit queue

```
fact SMUniqueness{

    no disjoint s1,s2: Store | s1.ticketqueue.manager=s2.ticketqueue.manager
    and s1.visitqueue.manager=s2.visitqueue.manager
    and s1.ticketqueue.manager=s2.visitqueue.manager
    and s1.visitqueue.manager=s2.ticketqueue.manager    
}
```

//different tickets/visits associated with the same user have different time

```
fact UniqueTimeUser {
    all u: User, t1, t2: Ticket,  v1,v2:Visit | ((u in t1.owner) and (u in t2.owner) and (u in v1.owner) and (u in v2.owner)
    and (t1 != t2) and (v1 !=v2)) 
    implies (t1.time != t2.time)
    and (v1.time != v2.time)
}
```

//different ticket and visit associated with the same user have different time

```
fact UniqueTimeUser2 {

    all u: User, t: Ticket,  v:Visit | ((u in t.owner) and (u in v.owner) )
    implies (v.time != t.time)
}
```

//Maximum number of visit with the same time for category

```
fact MaxTime{

all v:Visit, c: Category |(( c in v.category)) implies #v.time< c.simultaneous_seats

}
```

//Considering meaningfull integer value

```
fact PossibleValues{

all c: Category | c.simultaneous_seats>1 and c.simultaneous_seats<5
all s: Store |  s.max_simultaneous >0 and s.max_simultaneous<50
all t: Ticket | t.time.hour>7 and t.time.hour<21 and ((t.time.minute=15) || (t.time.minute=30) || (t.time.minute=45)) and t.time.second=0
all v: Visit | v.time.hour>7 and v.time.hour<21 and ((v.time.minute=15) || (v.time.minute=30) || (v.time.minute=45)) and v.time.second=0 and v.duration.hour=0 and v.duration.minute>0 and v.duration.minute=<30 and v.duration.second=0
all tq: TicketQueue | tq.max_visit=32
}

pred addTicket[ t :Ticket,ti,ti':Time, tq, tq':TicketQueue]{

//precondition
ti' not in Ticket.time
#tq.ticket< tq.max_visit //seats available
//postconditions
tq'.manager= tq.manager
tq'.ticket= tq.ticket+t
t in tq'.ticket
#tq'.ticket< tq.max_visit
all t': Ticket | t' in tq.ticket implies t' in tq'.ticket

}

pred show{

    #User = 4
    #Store = 2
    #SM = 2
    #Category = 3
    #TicketQueue = 2
       #VisitQueue= 2
    #Category = 5
    some v, v': Visit |  v.time != v'.time
    
    #Ticket = 5
    #Visit=5
    }

run show for 4
```

This is the complete response of Alloy terminal:
Executing "Run show for 4"
Solver=sat4j Bitwidth=4 MaxSeq=4 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
15098 vars. 840 primary vars. 17697 clauses. 28ms.
No instance found. Predicate may be inconsistent. 1ms.

Comment: To debug this, start over with the absolute minimum. Then add your constraints. There is no way I could make this extensive model work. Specifying is really hard so if you do not build from simple components, you're going to be lost.

Answer (score 3):

Have you run unsat core (using the MiniSAT with Unsat Core solver)? That might give you a hint. Another thought: I would simplify the model first and then only add features as you need them. I'm not sure that you really need to split the times into hours, minutes and seconds. That adds a lot of solver complexity, perhaps needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

General observations:

Some inconsistences in your show predicate:

```
 #Category = 3
 #Category = 5
```

Your scope is definitely too small. You can't expect 5 Visit elements if you have a general scope of 4.
I'd rewrite your show predicate and run command as follows:

```
pred show{
  some v, v': Visit |  v.time != v'.time
}

run show for 10 but 7 Int, exactly 4 User, exactly 2 Store, exactly 2 SM, exactly 3 Category, exactly 2 TicketQueue, exactly 2 VisitQueue, exactly 5 Ticket, exactly 5 Visit
```

Notice the 7 Int.
It means that your model will contain int type atoms that represent all the integers you can express with a bitwidth of 7 (interval is [-64,63]).

As Daniel wrote, i'd also advise to stay as abstract as possible when you model in Alloy and thus to prefer concepts over quantitative values.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the previous advice of simplifying and would add to use check statements to test as you go. I'm not an expert with Alloy, so I take it slow and test early and often.

One thing that sticks out to me immediately is that your "show" predicate seems to be specifying multiplicities for some signatures that are greater than those allowed by the run statement ("for 4"). I've never specified multiplicity in a predicate that way, so I don't know how Alloy handles that. Offhand, those seem like contradictory constraints.

Also, I figured this out the hard way, but Alloy counts instances (atoms) of extended signatures as instances (atoms) of the parent(s). So, be aware of that.